# Is there a way to unzip multiple files from a folder using gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to unzip multiple `.zip` files from a folder into another folder using Gradle. I am able to unzip files using Gradle, but I am trying to figure out how I can unzip all `.zip` files in a directory without having to specify the name of each `.zip` file. I will provide an example of what I currently have. The below code does not, and I am not sure what I need to change in order for me to achieve the desired result which is to unzip all the from one directory and place the unzipped files into a new directory.

```
task unzip(type: Copy) {
    from zipTree("$rootDir/destination_folder") {
        include "**/*.zip"
        into "$new_folder"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `zipTree` unzips a single `.zip` file and returns a `FileTree` with all the files inside the `.zip`. In your current code, Gradle interprets `"$rootDir/destination_folder"` as the path of the `.zip` file. It probably cannot find this `.zip` file but even if it could it would then limit the contained files to files that match `"**/*.zip"`, so only `.zip` files inside your `.zip` file would be copied.

Instead of directly using a `zipTree` that can only resolves a single `.zip` file you need to start with a `fileTree` to collect the `.zip` files inside your folder. You may then use `zipTree` on each of these files:

```
task unzip(type: Copy) {
    fileTree(dir: 'sourceDir', includes: ['**/*.zip']).each { zipFile ->
        from zipTree(zipFile)
    }
    into 'targetDir'
}
```